# I need help to prove that $\alpha=\beta$ and $w$ bisects the angle $\theta$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $u$ and $v$ be vectors and $w =\|v\|u + \|u\|v$.
Let $\theta$ be the angle between $u$ and $v$, $\alpha$ be the angle between $u$ and $w$ and $\beta$, be the angle between $v$ and $w$. Show that $w$ bisects angle $\theta$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, help them give their answers at the right level, and help prevent people from putting your questions on hold due to lack of effort. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly different (and more tedious than the others) approach that utilizes the fact that a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is completely specified by its action on a non-zero vector (because rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ commute).

First note that since $w = \|u\| \|v\| ( \frac{u}{\|u\|} + \frac{v}{\|v\|} )$, and the angles are unchanged by positive scalar multiplication, we can assume that $u,v$ are of unit norm to start with.

If $u=v$, then $w=2u$ and we see that all angles are zero, hence the angle is trivially bisected.

If $u=-v$, then $w=0$ and the angle is undefined.

So, suppose $u,v$ are not collinear. In particular, they span a two dimensional subspace. Consider the  basis vectors $b_1 = \frac{u+v}{\|u+v\|}$, $b_2 = \frac{u-v}{\|u-v\|}$. It is straightforward to check that these are orthonormal.

We have $u = \frac{\|u+v\|}{2} b_1 + \frac{\|u-v\|}{2} b_2$, $v = \frac{\|u+v\|}{2} b_1 - \frac{\|u-v\|}{2} b_2$, $w = \|u+v\| b_1$.

Define the rotation $Q$ by $Q b_1 = v$, and the rotation $J$ by $Jb_1 = b_2, Jb_2 = -b_1$. (Define $Qx=x,Jx=x$ for $x \in \operatorname{sp} \{ b_1, b_2 \}^\bot $.) Since $Q,J$ commute, we have $Q b_2 = Q J b_1 = J Q b_1$ (so $Q$ is completely specified by its action on $b_1$).

In the following, let $z$ represent an element of $\operatorname{sp} \{ b_1, b_2 \}^\bot $.

We have
$$Q(\alpha_1 b_1 + \alpha_2 b_2 +z) = (\alpha_1 \frac{\|u+v\|}{2} + \alpha_2 \frac{\|u-v\|}{2}) b_1 + (-\alpha_1 \frac{\|u+v\|}{2} + \alpha_2 \frac{\|u-v\|}{2}) b_2 + z$$
from which it follows that
$$Q^T(\alpha_1 b_1 + \alpha_2 b_2 +z) = (\alpha_1 \frac{\|u+v\|}{2} - \alpha_2 \frac{\|u-v\|}{2}) b_1 + (\alpha_1 \frac{\|u+v\|}{2} + \alpha_2 \frac{\|u-v\|}{2}) b_2 + z$$
 and so we have $Q^T b_1 = u$.

Hence we have $Q \frac{w}{\|w\|} = v$ and $Q^T \frac{w}{\|w\|} = u$. Since $Q^T$ represents a rotation by the same angle in the opposite direction to $Q$, we have the desired result.

The angle can be computed from the unique solution (modulo $2 \pi$) to the equations $\cos (-\theta) = \frac{\|u+v\|}{2}$, $\sin(-\theta) = \frac{\|u-v\|}{2}$ (the $-\theta$ arises from my unfortunate choice of $Q b_1 = v$, and for the angle to be in the standard direction with respect to the basis $b_1,b_2$).

Comment: This question's very likely of high school, or very close, level. To get into linear algebra to make a point which I believe is moot (since the sign of the cosine is irrelevant, because with an angle bisector we do *not* care which "direction" the bisector goes!) is, perhaps, a little too much for this.

Comment: @DonAntonio: The question was to show that $w$ bisects the angle. The $\cos$ proofs show that the absolute value of the angle between $w,u$ and $w,v$ is the same. It is easy to complete the proof in many ways, but without showing that the angle between $u,v$ is twice that between $u,w$, the proof is incomplete.

Comment: @ copper.hat I still agree with DonAntonio about this; angles between vectors are in $[0,\pi]$ by definition, so there is no sign issue involved.  Once you know that $\alpha=\beta$, it follows that w (or possibly -w) bisects $\theta$.

Comment: @user84413: It is a tiny point. Somewhere in the proof you **must** rely on the fact that it is a two dimensional problem. If not, I can trivially construct examples with three lines and the angle between each pair is the same. Clearly not a bisector. Neither your proof, nor DonAntonio's relied on **any** aspect of $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence the proof cannot be complete. Robjohn's proof works because two dimensions in implicit in the geometry.

Comment: @ copper.hat  I agree with you that we are using the fact that the 3 vectors are coplanar.  (I mentioned this in my first reply to you, but not explicitly in my answer itself.)  Maybe it would have been a little better if we had explicitly stated this, or drawn a diagram like robjohn did.

Comment: @user84413: Frankly, I have often found that angles are perplexing beasts in that geometrically evident facts require a fair bit of analytical calisthenics to establish. And I am far more secure with my analysis than I am with my geometry :-).

Answer (score 2):

We have to assume that $u$ and $v$ are not in opposite directions, for then
$$
w=\|v\|u+\|u\|v=0
$$
**Hint:**
$$
\frac{w}{\|u\|\|v\|}=\frac{u}{\|u\|}+\frac{v}{\|v\|}
$$
By the Parallelogram Rule for Vector Addition, the sum of two unit vectors bisects the angle between them:

$\hspace{32mm}$[image]

> Since $ADBC$ is a parallelogram, $\angle CAB=\angle DBA$ and $\angle CBA=\angle DAB$. Since $\overline{AB}$ is a shared side, $\triangle ABC=\triangle BAD$. Since $\overline{AC}=\overline{AD}$, we have that all four sides of $ADBC$ are equal. Thus, $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles and $\angle CAB=\angle CBA$.
>
>
>  Thus, $\angle CAB=\angle DAB$ and therefore, $\overline{AB}$ bisects $\angle CAD$.

Comment: +1: Geometric proofs are so much more succinct and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

$u\cdot w=|u||w|\cos \alpha$ and $v\cdot w=|v||w|\cos \beta$, where

$u\cdot w=u\cdot (|v|u+|u|v)=|u|^2|v|+|u|(u\cdot v)=|u|(|u||v|+u\cdot v)$ and

$v\cdot w=v\cdot (|v|u+|u|v)=(u\cdot v)|v|+|u||v|^2=|v|(|u||v|+u\cdot v)$.

Now use this to show that $\cos \alpha = \cos \beta$.

Notice that $\alpha, \beta\in[0,\pi/2]$ since w is a sum of positive multiples of u and v (or since $u\cdot w>0$ and $v\cdot w>0$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality),
so 
w actually bisects $\theta$.

Comment: How does this show that the angle is bisected?

Comment: @copper.hat I may be wrong about this, but I thought that since the angle between w and u is the same as the angle between w and v (and the 3 vectors are coplanar), w must bisect the angle between u and v.

Comment: See my comment to DonAntonio above.

Comment: @copper.hat Since $\cos\alpha=\cos\beta$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both in $[0,\pi]$, we know that $\alpha=\beta$; but you have a good point:  If both angles are greater than $\pi/2$, then w could be pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: Look, I know the answer is true, but the above answers involving $\cos$ do not distinguish the signs. The angle is in $[0,2 \pi)$ (or whatever way you want to dice it up). The cross product, for example, distinguishes sign (not a pun!). It is a property of rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that makes this work.

Comment: The formula Don Antonio and I are using gives an angle in $[0,\pi]$, since $\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{u\cdot v}{|u||v|}$; so the problem is not sign ambiguity (unless you are referring to the dot products).  In any case, thanks for pointing out that there was something missing in my solution.

Comment: My point is that if you compute the angle as above between $e_1$ and $e_1 \pm e_2$ you will get the same value, so the inner product is insensitive to 'direction'. The question was to show that $w$ **bisects** the angle between $u,v$. What the '$\cos$' answers above is to show that the angle (ignoring sign) between $w,u$ is the same as the angle (ignoring sign) between $w,v$. The part that is missing in the proof is to show that the 'direction's are opposite. I know it is true, but the proof's do not demonstrate it.

Comment: I have added a tedious answer which illustrates my rather pedantic point.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos \alpha=\frac{\langle u,w\rangle}{||u||\,||w||}=\frac{\langle u,||v||u+||u||v\rangle}{||u||\,||w||}=\frac{||u||^2\,||v||+||u||\langle u,v\rangle}{||u||\,||w||}$$

$$\cos\beta=\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{||v||\,||w||}=\frac{\langle v,||v||u+||u||v\rangle}{||v||\,||w||}=\frac{||v||\langle v,u\rangle+||u||\,||v||^2}{||v||\,||w||}$$

so

$$\cos\alpha=\cos\beta\iff$$

$$\iff ||u||^2||v||^2||w||+||u||\,||v||\,||w||\langle u,v\rangle=||u||^2||v||^2||w||+||u||\,||v||\,||w||\langle v,u\rangle $$

so assuming we're in a **real** inner product linear space, the above is certainly an equality.

Comment: How does this show that the angle is bisected?

Comment: It shows that $\;\alpha=\beta\;$ and thus the angle $\;\theta\;$ is bisected...

Comment: No, it shows that $\cos \alpha = \cos \beta$. You need some sign information?

Comment: Not really: I'm assuming that, as usual in analytic geometry and algebra, when talking of angles between lines/vectors it is mean the acute ones...if it is otherwise it should be, imo, be explicitly said.

Comment: Well, I know that the result is true, and the answer above does not contradict it, but it doesn't show that the angles are equal.

Comment: I think it does under my basic and, imo, standard assumption on what "angle between" is usually understood.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was not what I intended to write. I meant to write that the proof demonstrates that the (absolute value of) angles are equal, but not that the angle is bisected. It has nothing to do with the angle being acute (which it must be), it is to do with the sign of the angle (which $\cos$ is immune to). I have added a tedious answer which illustrates my rather pedantic point.